# Should I use singular or plural noun in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, singular-vs-plural

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. I think people are more concerned these days about being successful in
>    their **career**.
> 2. I think people are more concerned these days about being
>    successful in their **careers**.

If both are correct, could you please tell me the difference between the two?

I guess that both are correct but their meaning is different:

- The first one just mentions that they are more concerned about their
  job. It points out that we are talking about people's career not other things such as family life.
- The second one also emphasizes that each person might have a different job, but all of them are more concerned. I
  mean, the second one tells that people are more concerned no matter
  what their jobs are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither form is wrong, and both will be understood. It's a slight change of perspective, from talking about people in general to thinking about them as separate individuals.